# Are qq-plots dependent on covariate effects?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, qq-plot

I have $Y$ as a response in a multiple regression. I plot `qqplot` with K after using `lm` in R.

Is the resulting plot only dependent on $Y$ or do the covariates matter?

In other words, is `qqnorm(Y)` the same as `qqnorm(lm)`?

If not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 1):

`qqnorm` looks at the standardized residuals for a linear model. The unconditional $Y$ can have a highly non-normal distribution depending on how your $X$ is distributed, but still meet all the assumptions for exact finite sample inference.

As a note you cannot call `qqnorm` directly on a `lm` object, there is no method implemented for it. However, if you use the `plot` method on a fit object, one of the graphics you get is this QQ_normal plot. Specifically the help file says:

> The ‘S-L’, the Q-Q, and the Residual-Leverage plot, use standardized
>   residuals which have identical variance (under the hypothesis). They
>   are given as R[i] / (s * sqrt(1 - h.ii)) where h.ii are the diagonal
>   entries of the hat matrix, influence()$hat (see also hat), and where
>   the Residual-Leverage plot uses standardized Pearson residuals
>   (residuals.glm(type = "pearson")) for R[i].